# Major Issues with element.style

Tags: html, css, wordpress, inline

I am having major issues with my logo and navigation bar on my website. I am trying to increase the size to make it a bit bigger when you scroll down the page as it's very small and hard to read. I edited my css code in the backend but it looks like my element.style is overriding it and I am unable to find the code in the backend.

http://vahanadvertising.com/clients/tsl/

CSS Code:

```
.page-header.sticky .logo>img{
    width:auto !important;
        margin-top: 10px !important;
        height: 53px !important;
        margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```

Inline Code:

```
margin-top: 10px;
height: 33px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

Is anyone able to help me out with overriding the inline code so my css works? I have tried using !important; but that didn't help. Many thanks.

Comment: You're not using the right selector

Comment: It looks OK here (chrome)

Comment: If you scroll down the page you will notice a bar appears at the top with the navigation and logo on the left hand side but it's very hard to read. Need it bigger. Think it's a sticky menu

Comment: Amit what do you mean by selector? Sorry not very familiar with coding in general